# Axios API Client - Data after transformation must be a string, an ArrayBuffer, a Buffer, or a Stream

Tags: typescript, axios

**The Scenario**

I'm looking to send a request through an OpenAPI Client that has been generated, so I'm installing this as a dependency and then looking to interact with the OpenAPI Client using Axios to use one of the methods available.

Note this is within a Node environment.

The method in question looks to change a status which requires the following information:

- `identifier`
- `name`
- `document`

When looking to pass the `document` part of the params I'm doing this via the following method below:

```
async function getFormData(): Promise<any> {
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../resources/document.pdf');
  const file = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  console.log(file); // Should show <Buffer ...>
  console.log(typeof file); // Should be 'object'
  console.log(file instanceof Buffer); // Should be true
  return file;
}
```

This function then passes the output for the request.

**The Problem**

`Data after transformation must be a string, an ArrayBuffer, a Buffer, or a Stream`

We are getting the error displayed above when sending the request.

As you can see from the console logs shown below the content is as a Buffer, I'm wondering what else I can do to get this working within my automated test.

**Console Log**

```
console.log <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 34 0a 25 f6 e4 fc df 0a 31 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 0a 2f 54 79 70 65 20 2f 43 61 74 61 6c 6f 67 0a 2f 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 20 ... 113376 more bytes>
at getFormData (src/helpers/form-data.ts:7:11)

console.log object
at getFormData (src/helpers/form-data.ts:8:11)

console.log true
```

**Error Message**

```
      AxiosError {
        message: 'Data after transformation must be a string, an ArrayBuffer, a Buffer, or a Stream',
        name: 'AxiosError',
        code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
        config: {
          transitional: {
            silentJSONParsing: true,
            forcedJSONParsing: true,
            clarifyTimeoutError: false
          },
          env: { FormData: [Function] },
          validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
          headers: {
            Accept: '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2'
          },
          baseURL: 'https://test.com',
          method: 'post',
          data: FormData { [Symbol(state)]: [Array] },
          url: '/123'
        }
      }
```